# Pass complete URL as a query parameter in REACT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a complete URL as a query param from front-end(React JS). Meaning there will be a input-box where user can enter the URL on click of submit I am sending it as query param. But I am getting an weird error after I am hosting the application in cloud. In local it's working fine. In the back-end I am using node.js, I tried to encoding the URL and passed it to the required function it's also not working and also I have tried to stringfy it, it's also not working. Could any one help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!
Error: Basically from React when I am trying to pass complete URL like( https://testsite.com) it is not getting passed to backend, with the same code If I enter some string or numeric value like (abc or 123) the request is passing.

```
cons isExists = async(tbData, colName, value) => {
   const res = await API.IfExists(
     EndPoints.IfExists(tbData, colName, value)
  )
return response; 
}

const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
e.preventDefault()
const isUrlPresent = await isExists('URL', url)
if(!isUrlPresent.data){
 await addData(url)
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry I can’t guess which error this might have caused.  Can you narrow it down by providing the error details?

Comment: Hi @James basically it's not allowing to send the complete URL as query param.

Comment: Please provide the error details from the console.

Comment: In console log I can only see the following error: BadResponse..

Comment: Where is your addData() Function ?? provide full code.

Answer (score 0):

The question is incomplete but I'd recommend to ensure that the URL is properly encoded before sending it as a query parameter.

```
const encodedUrl = encodeURIComponent(userEnteredUrl);
```

Comment: I've tried with encodeURIComponent, it's also not working.

Comment: try checking backend logs, Sometimes, server configurations can cause issues with certain characters in URLs. Inspect Network Requests